# Changing the suffix of the name of a compound loses one hydrogen atom?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I just chanced upon these intriguing pubchem entries: [Ethyl Carbylamine](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4474585) and [Ethyl Isocyanide](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Isocyanoethane#section=Top). Their structures - as given on that site - are respectively:

[image] and [image].

Notice that the only difference is the H atom on ethyl carbylamine, which is missing in ethyl isocyanide!

I always understood *carbylamine* and *isocyanide* being interchangeable suffixes for an IUPAC name, but it seems like I've been proved wrong.

> What is the reason for such an anomaly in the structures of these two compounds?

Comment: No, you weren't wrong. PubChem isn't as good as one could hope.

Comment: @Mithoron  Could you please post an answer so I could accept it? Thank you!

Comment: Both carbylamine and isocyanide are same. It is only that carbylamine has become obsolete. See: https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C00853